# Configure kafka_server_jaas.conf for multiple listeners

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to migrate away from keeping my SASL authentication within my `server.properties` file and instead in my `kafka_server_jaas.conf` file. However I am getting slightly confused as the settings used in `server.properties` do not seem to map to the settings used in `kafka_server_jaas.conf`.

Here is the existing setup.
`server.properties:`

```
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL_SASL:SASL_SSL,INTERNAL:SASL_SSL,EXTERNAL_SSL:SSL,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
listeners=EXTERNAL_SASL://:9094,INTERNAL://:9091,EXTERNAL_SSL://:9093,EXTERNAL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=OMITTED

listener.name.external_sasl.sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
listener.name.external_sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username="broker-admin" password="xx" \
user_admin="xx"\
user_broker="xx";

listener.name.internal.sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
listener.name.internal_sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
username="broker-admin" password="xx" \
user_admin="xx"\
user_broker="xx";
```

This works as I would expect. I am able to interact with the cluster using the credentials in the `server.properties` file.

When configuring `kafka_server_jaas.conf` all of the examples indicate that my config needs to look like this:

```
KafkaServer {        
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="broker-admin" password="xx"
user_admin="xx"
user_broker="xx";
};
```

This leads to my question, do I not need to specify which listener (external_sasl or internal) that `kafka_server_jaas.conf` should use? To me, the config should be:

```
KafkaServer {        
listener.name.external_sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="broker-admin" password="xx"
user_admin="xx"
user_broker="xx";
};
```

But this does not work.

Is anyone able to point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to this:

The correct configuration for specifying the listen in the `kafka_server_jaas.conf` file is:

```
external_sasl.KafkaServer {        
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="broker-admin" password="xx"
user_admin="xx"
user_broker="xx";
};

internal.KafkaServer {        
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required 
username="broker-admin" password="xx"
user_admin="xx"
user_broker="xx";
};
```